# Как сделать из нескольких ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> один ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>

Tags: android

Здраствуйте , у меня есть функция которая возвращает

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>
```

таких функций и мета несколько

мне нада из нескольких `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>` собрать один

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>
```

и потом послать этот один  ArrayList в BaseAdapter

песал следущий код

```
  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>  getContacts = new ArrayList<>();
    getContacts.addAll(...function name return arraylist....);
    getContacts.addAll(...function name return arraylist....);
    adapter = new Today_Adapter(getActivity(), getListView(), getContacts, Colors.getColors());
```

НО Получил следущую ошибку

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getImportantForAccessibility()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Прозреваю, что или адаптер в `getView` возвращает null, или в одном из возвращаемых списков есть `null`, и вы его как-то странно обрабатываете. Выведите в лог `getContacts`, возможно всплывет.

Comment: да вы были правы одна из функсий возвращала null большое спосибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно ваш метод `getListView()` возвращает `null`. Объединение двух `ArrayList` в один у вас верное.

Comment: не из за этого выдает ошибку java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object[] java.util.Collection.toArray()' on a null object reference на getContacts.addAll(...function name return arraylist....);

Comment: @DavidKern Приведите код адаптера, что-то с вьюхой у вас не так